# How to make UICollectionView items display proportionally on different iPhone screens in objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I added a collection view to a screen on my iOS objective-c app, I set the collection view cell size and looks like the image below on the storyboard: 
[image: collection view on screen]

When I use the assistant inspector to preview how it would look on wider iPhone screens in score this is what I got for 5.5 inch device: as shown in the image below:
[image: collection view on larger iPhone screen]

How can I make the item arrangement proportional on all screen devices irrespective of the size, the space between items should be the same and line spaces also.
I have tried resizing a couple of times and even added some constraints but didn't work. What am I suppose to do?

Comment: Try working on constraints for a while. That's what constraints is for

Comment: I have, it arranges well for 4 inch devices but that wide space appears for 5inch devices...

Comment: T Israel@please try my answer it will surely work for you

Answer (score 0):

Proposing an alternative solution to your problem: another way to go about this is by setting up your constraints through [Visual Format Language (VFL)](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/VisualFormatLanguage.html). With views that are pinned both vertically and horizontally as is in your screenshot, it wouldn't be a lot of work to use VFL.

An example implementation of the horizontal constraint for the top 2 image views:

```
NSLayoutConstraint *horizontalConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-[imageView1]-[imageView2]-|"
                                                                 options:NSLayoutFormatAlignAllCenterY
                                                                 metrics:0
                                                                   views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(imageView1,imageView2)];
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: The aren't actually 2, it's suppose to be a I idiolect ion view cell, I just increased the number of static cells to 4 just to see how it will look

Answer (score 0):

You try this

```
1.  Assign equal width from button1 to button2.
2.  Assign equal height from button1 to button2.
3.  Assign horizontal spacing between both buttons.
4.  Assign leading space from button1 to its superview.
5.  Assign trailing space from button2 to its superview.
6.  Assign horizontal centre in container (means Align Centre X to : SuperView).
```

I hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Do following steps to achieve the desired output

1) You need to override data source method of `collectionView` which returns size to the each cell.
Here is the code you need to add.

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return CGSizeMake(collectionView.frame.size.width /2, collectionView.frame.size.width /2+lableheight);

}
```

> Note - lableHieght - you need to take your lable height which you specified
>   in the cell in storyboard

2) Also make sure that you add constraints to for all sides of image like
leading ,trailing ,top & bottom to contentView.